# App Working As Expected in the Tizen TV Simulator, but not in the Emulator

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-web-simulator

I am developing an application for Samsung Tizen Smart TV's. I have a strange problem. The app plays sound and responds to remote controller keys in the **simulator**, but the sound is not playing and the keys are not working in the **emulator**.

I am using HTML5 Audio tags.

What could be the reason? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

A very basic web page as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
   <audio id="audioMain" src="http://streams.myabcradio.com/api/914/320/stream?user=justanuser&pass=justapassword" autoplay="autplay" preload="none"></audio>
</body> 
</html>
```

plays sound in the simulator, but not in the emulator. I tried adding

but still no sound...

Comment: Nice question, but you may want to post environment details (OS, SDK version, etc) and minimal code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added sample code in the Edit section. Even the basic HTML5 Audio tag does not produce sound in the emulator.

Comment: have you added http://tizen.org/privilege/internet and http://tizen.org/privilege/volume.set previleges in your project ?

Comment: Thanks, but still not working...

Comment: You may try posting the issue on SamsungDForum which is official community of Samsung Tizen TV Developers https://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumDashBoard/cd10341507013d28

Answer (score 2):

Privilege could be issue here. Please add these privileges required to play audio and respond to remote controller keys.

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/tv.audio"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/tv.inputdevice"/>
```

Comment: I had already tried adding them, but the app still does not produce sound in the emulator, and does not respond to the remote controller events.

Answer (score 1):

Launch the 'Update Manager'->

Go to 'Installed Packages' tab ->

Extras ->

Samsung TV extensions (public)->

**Remove**

Then Install the Samsung TV Extension again and Create new emulator. There is a good possibility that your current installation is having issues.

Comment: Thanks, but that did not help either... I suspect that HTML5 Audio tag is supported in the emulator...?

Answer (score 1):

Checklist.

1. Internet Privilege
   `<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>`
2. Access Control
   `<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>`
3. Check your Emulator's Network. is it really connected to internet?
4. Test local media file (packaged in app) with audio tag. latest tv emulator webkit version is 538.1 Check is it really support to play that media file/stream.